# How to fetch data from MongoDB in dataweave according to passing previous fields we transformed in Mule 4

Tags: mongodb, mule, dataweave, mule4

How to fetch data from MongoDB in dataweave according to passing previous fields we transformed in Mule 4.

So After fetching data from one collection and while trasforming that data into Json I want to fecth data from other collection using current values of Json and add that data into same JSON.

More clear about question: I want to aggregate two collections data in one JSON which I will be insert back in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would approach this the way your question is asked but it is possible. Take a look at this: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.examples/dataweave-with-flowreflookup/minor/2.1/ You will need to be able to log-in to view all the details.

A second option is to use what is called a lookup, it has some considerations so check the documentation carefully: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-mule-functions-lookup

Final approach, perform your first query but direct the output to a variable not payload. You can access the input you need for your second query. Now you can use Dataweave as normal to construct the final output you need from your variable and the second query. HTH.

Comment: I am trying lookup which is working for leve 3 json beyond json it is more complex. Thank you Adams